# Asp.Net MVC тег asp-... не работает

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. Изучаю MVC по книге, и автор использует тэг
`<input asp-for="Name"/>`
или что то связанное с asp-... любое действие с этим тэгом - игнорируется. 
Страница при принятии формы c этим тегом никак не реагирует, но при замене на
`<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name"  />` - форма отсылается и все работает. В чем собственно проблема?

Comment: То же изучаю MVC но такого свойства **asp-for** у тэга **input** не встречал ранее. Скорее всего автор использовал создание своего атрибута. Смотрите в сторону @Html.Helper

Comment: Хороший вопрос: в чём проблема, если всё работает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asp-for="Name"` и прочих asp-атрибутов в ASP.NET MVC нет и никогда не было. Проверьте свою книгу - скорее всего она рассказывает вам про ASP.NET Core или ASP.NET vNext (старое название)

Если в книге и правда написано что такие атрибуты есть в MVC - выкиньте ее.

---

Аналогом того что вы написали в MVC является вызов хелпера `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)` или даже `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)`. Но для более сложных случаев порой проще написать вручную чем искать как еще это можно сделать.

Comment: Да поглядел и действительно так. Получается, в таком случае надо использовать стандартный input? или все же есть какая то замена?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-core/2665/tag-helpers#t=20171010113829396698
Похоже, значения атрибутов можно заменить на параметры get формы

Comment: спасибо за ответ @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name) это помогло.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka вы это к чему?